# Linq To Entities, Using where clause on table before left join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to filter my dataset before I do join in Linq to Entities but I could not find the way to do it. My current linq query is that makes left joins is :

```
from m in Products
          join f in FileFolders on m.ProductCode equals f.Name into list1
          from l1 in list1.DefaultIfEmpty()
          join p in Files on l1.FileFolderID equals p.FileFolderID into list2
          // I want something like p.Name == "Test" here
          from l2 in list2.DefaultIfEmpty()                                                     
          join b in BaseReferenceFile on l2.BaseReferenceFileID equals b.BaseReferenceFileID into list3
          from l3 in list3.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new
          {
              //select some stuff here                           
          };
```

I want to filter Files collection such that only the files with name "Test" are joined with l1.

I have tried filtering on l2 with `l2.Name == "Test"` but it is not working. It generates a weird query with an inner join and a left join.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
join p in Files.Where(m => m.Name == "Test") on l1.FileFolderID equals p.FileFolderID into list2
```

Comment: thank you, I will give it a shot.Is it possible to do this with Linq query syntax ?

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi hmmm, I must admit I don't know, I'm not used to that syntax. By the way, you already have a `DefaultIfEmpty()` in your query ;)

Comment: :) I am ok with it, I was just curious. Thanks it is working.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work but this will query each time (for each record):

```
   join p in (from f in Files where f.Name == "Test") on l1.FileFolderID equals p.FileFolderID into list2
```

**its best to use *where before select*.**

```
          ...from l3 in list3.DefaultIfEmpty()
          where (l1 !=null ? l1.Name == "Test" : true)
          select new
          {
              //select some stuff here                           
          };
```